# MongoDB aggregate exceed 16M

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

hi, guys!
    I want to get top-100 item in my mongodb.So I use aggregate pipeline, but "exceed 16M" happen.
    I looked for some information, the information suggest that mongo version is too old.In fact, the mongo that is being used is the 2.4 version.Our data is very large, so upgrade has lots of risk.
    I want to know if there is any way to solve this problem——"exceed 16M".
    Thank you!

Comment: 2.4 is very old—you really should consider upgrading.

Comment: Our data size is too large. Upgrade cluster has lots of risk.And out cluster version is too old, upgrade is difficulty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't already done so, you can use $project to remove fields that you don't need.  Worst case you could even reduce the size of length field names by renaming them in a $project stage.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.
I try to use $project. I find that it is very slow when I use $project options in aggregate command.I want to know why it gets slow.